# Fastest way to remove huge number of elements from an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have dynamic array that contains thousands of elements or even more, in order not to consume a large size of memory, I can remove unwanted elements from it (i.e elements have been used and no need for them any more) so from the beginning I can allocate a smaller memory size by estimating the maximum required size after removing the elements each time.

I use this way but it takes a very very long time to finish, sometime takes 30 minutes!

```
int x, y ;
for (x = 0 ; x<number_of_elements_to_remove ; x++){
    for (y = 0 ; y<size_of_array; y++ ){
            array[y] = array[y+1];
    }
}
```

Is there a faster way than this?

Comment: I don't understand the example.

Comment: Unless I am misreading your code example, x is not used anywhere in the other loop or array indexing, so what is the point?

Comment: What do you want to do? Is it that you want to clear the data in some elements of the array, or do you want to reduce the memory by permanently deleting unwanted blocks?

Comment: Did you test this code (on smaller inputs)? Does it work as you intend?

Comment: There are two possibilities IMHO: allocate another array for wanted values, copy only them, and then deallocate the old array; or use linked list.

Comment: One way is to make "an array of pointers to Data" instead of "an array of Data", and each element is filled with dynamically allocated memory. In this way 1) memory continuity requirement is relaxed so allocation is more likely to successfully in a fragmented memory pool; 2) the array itself is smaller so resizing it is cheaper; 3) or you don't even need to resize it because your use case is "shrink only", so you can just deallocate the pointer and then assign null to it to mark it non-valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of removing elements one at a time, with two loops making for an O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution, you can make a single loop, with a single read and a single write index. Go through the array, copying items as you go:

```
int rd = 0, wr = 0;
while (rd != size_of_array) {
    if (keep_element(array[rd])) {
        array[wr++] = array[rd];
    }
    rd++;
}
```

At the end of the loop `wr` is the number of elements kept in the `array`.

Answer (score 1):

as I noticed you want to only delete elements from the start of the array, try this:

```
  int x;
        for(x = 0 ; x< size_of_array - number_of_elements_to_remove; x++)
           array[x] = array[number_of_elements_to_remove + x];
```

this way you're using one for loop which reduces the complexity alot

Answer (score 0):

It seems you essentially do

```
int y;
for (y = 0; y<size_of_array; y++){
   array[y] = array[y+numbre_of_elements_to_remove];
}
```

The above should be faster, but there are still some caveats / problems with your code (e.g., access beyond the end od the array).

Comment: And with yours.  If you run your loop as such, you'll get to `y == size_of_array - 1` trying to access `array[y+number_of_elements_to_remove]` which deals to access array past of bounds as soon as `number_of_elements_to_remove > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to defragment the array.

```
int sparse_to_compact(int*arr, int total, int*is_valid) {
        int i = 0;
        int last = total - 1;
        // trim the last invalid elements
        for(; last >= 0 && !is_valid[last]; last--); // trim invalid elements from last

        // now we keep swapping the invalid with last valid element
        for(i=0; i < last; i++) {
                if(is_valid[i])
                        continue;
                arr[i] = arr[last]; // swap invalid with the last valid
                last--;
                for(; last >= 0 && !is_valid[last]; last--); // trim invalid elements
        }
        return last+1; // return the compact length of the array
}
```

I copied the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821123/removing-elements-from-an-array-in-c/35594291#35594291) answer.

I think more efficient way is to use a link-list of buckets. And the buckets are managed by bit-string memory manager. It is like the following,

```
struct elem {
     uint32_t index; /* helper to locate it's position in the array */
     int x; /* The content/object kept in the array */
}
```

Suppose, our array content is `int` and it is encapsulated in a structure named `struct elem`.

```
enum {
     MAX_BUCKET_SIZE = 1024,
     MAX_BITMASK_SIZE = (MAX_BUCKET_SIZE + 63) >> 6,
};

struct bucket {
    struct bucket*next; /* link to the next bucket */
    uint64_t usage[MAX_BITMASK_SIZE]; /* track memory usage */
    struct elem[MAX_BUCKET_SIZE]; /* the array */
};
```

A bucket is defined as an array of `struct elem` and usage mask.

```
struct bucket_list {
    struct bucket*head; /* dynamically allocated bucket */
}container;
```

And a bucket list is a linked list containing all the buckets.

So we need to write memory manager code.

At first we need new bucket to be allocated when needed.

```
struct bucket*bk = get_empty_bucket(&container);
if(!bk) { /* no empty bucket */
    /* allocate a bucket */
    struct bucket*bk = (struct bucket*)malloc(sizeof(struct bucket));
    assert(bk);
    /* cleanup the usage flag */
    memset(bk->usage, 0, sizeof(bk->usage));
    /* link the bucket */
    bk->next = container.head;
    container.head = bk; 
}
```

Now as we have the bucket we need to set the value in the array when needed.

```
for(i = 0; i < MAX_BITMASK_SIZE; i++) {
    uint64_t bits = ~bk.usage[i];
    if(!bits) continue; /* no space */
    /* get the next empty position */
    int bit_index = _builtin_ctzl(bits);
    int index = (i<<6)+bit_index;
    /* set the array value */
    bk->elem[index].index = index;
    bk->elem[index].x = 34/* my value */;
    bk.usage[i] |= 1<<bit_index; /* mark/flag the array element as used */
}
```

Deleting the array elements is easy as to mark them unused. Now when all the elements in a bucket is unused we can delete the bucket from the link-list.

We can sometimes defragment buckets or optimize them to fit in smaller space. Otherwise when we assign new elements we can select more crowded buckets over less crowded one. When we delete we can swap the element of less crowded one into more crowded one.

It is possible to delete elements of array in efficient way,

```
int remove_element(int*from, int total, int index) {
        if(index != (total-1))
                from[index] = from[total-1];
        return total; // **DO NOT DECREASE** the total here
}
```

It is done by swapping the element with the last value.